# Is it possible to check if a user literal is defined for given type and argument?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, c++17

I want to check at compile-time if user literal `_name` is defined for type `Ret` and argument `Arg`. While I have half-solution, it requires the literal `operator` to be defined at least once:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct one { };
struct two { };

// we need at least one of these definitions for template below to compile
one operator"" _x(char const*) {return {};}
two operator"" _x(unsigned long long int) {return {};}

template<class T, class S, class = void>
struct has_literal_x : std::false_type
{  };

template<class T, class S>
struct has_literal_x <T, S,
    std::void_t<decltype((T(*)(S))(operator"" _x))>
    > : std::true_type
{ };

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_literal_x<one, char const*>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_literal_x<two, unsigned long long int>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << has_literal_x<one, unsigned long long int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_literal_x<two, char const*>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << has_literal_x<int, char const*>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
0
0
0
```

But if there isn't at least one definition of possibly overloaded user literal, this solution will not work. Is there any way to check it even for non-existing literals (possibly the same way we can check if class `X` has member `member`, but I don't know if it's viable in this case)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to check if an user literal is defined for given type and argument?

The (short) answer is **yes**.

---

As an example, you can use the following specialization in your example code:

```
template<class T, class S> 
struct has_literal_x <T, S,
      std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(operator""_x(std::declval<S>())), T>::value>
    > : std::true_type
{ };
```

That quickly becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct one { };
struct two { };

//one operator"" _x(char const*) { return {}; }
//two operator"" _x(unsigned long long int) { return {}; }

template<class T, class S, class = void>
struct has_literal_x : std::false_type
{  };

template<class T, class S> 
struct has_literal_x <T, S, 
      std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(operator""_x(std::declval<S>())), T>::value> 
    > : std::true_type
{ };

int main()
{  
    std::cout << has_literal_x<one, char const*>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_literal_x<two, unsigned long long int>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << has_literal_x<one, unsigned long long int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_literal_x<two, char const*>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << has_literal_x<int, char const*>::value << std::endl;
}
```

The output is the expected one: `0` for all of them.

---

Another way to do that in C++14 (mostly inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39726133/4987285) answer of @Jarod42) is by means of a template variable.
As an example:

```
template<typename T, typename S, typename = void>
constexpr bool has_literal_v = false;

template<typename T, typename S>
constexpr bool has_literal_v<T, S, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(operator""_x(std::declval<S>())), T>::value>> = true;
```

The `main` would become instead:

```
int main()
{  
    std::cout << has_literal_v<one, char const*> << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_literal_v<two, unsigned long long int> << std::endl;

    std::cout << has_literal_v<one, unsigned long long int> << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_literal_v<two, char const*> << std::endl;

    std::cout << has_literal_v<int, char const*> << std::endl;
}
```

I find it easy to read and that's a `constexpr` variable. What else?

Comment: Note this solution doesn't quite work if operator is defined after the type trait is defined in GCC at least: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f70eb6cbf236473

Answer (score 5):

With [`is_detected`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249985/how-to-require-an-exact-function-signature-in-the-detection-idiom/45250180#45250180) functions family, you may just do

```
template <typename T>
using has_literal_x_type = decltype(operator"" _x(std::declval<T>()));

template <typename Ret, typename T>
using has_literal_x = std::is_same<Ret, detected_t<has_literal_x_type, T>>;
```

And test it with

```
static_assert(!has_literal_x<one, char const*>::value, "unexpected");
static_assert(!has_literal_x<one, unsigned long long int>::value, "unexpected");
static_assert(!has_literal_x<two, char const*>::value, "unexpected");
static_assert(!has_literal_x<two, unsigned long long int>::value, "unexpected");
static_assert(!has_literal_x<int, char const*>::value, "unexpected");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e943ecc9b824233)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `std::declval<T>()` instead of `std::declval<T>`?

Comment: @skypjack: Sure, fixed, thanks. I didn't want to add the valid case in Demo as OP expected that the operator may not appears, so I miss that typo...

Comment: Well, this is beast! Great solution in general terms, but I expected any working solution, and skypjack was first this time and did it with generally known syntax :) Although `is_detected` would be The Winner of question "How to simplify complicated SFINAE syntax".

Comment: @BlackMoses I added another snippet to my answer with a solution based on a template variable, that is mostly inspired by this one. Can I participate to the _The Winner of Question "How to simplify complicated SFINAE syntax"_ contest? :-)

Comment: @skypjack Here you go :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727409/how-to-simplify-complicated-sfinae-syntax-in-pre-c11-c11-14-and-17