# How to simplify complicated SFINAE syntax, in pre-C++11, C++11, 14 and 17?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, c++03, c++17

This question was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39726133/5405086). I wonder what are/were the best ways to simplify it in given standards. One I know and personally used/still use since C++14 is macro `REQUIRES(x)`:

With definition:

```
template<long N>
struct requires_enum
{
    enum class type
    {
        none,
        all
    };
};

#define REQUIRES(...) requires_enum<__LINE__>::type = \
                      requires_enum<__LINE__>::type::none, \
                      bool PrivateBool = true, \
                      typename std::enable_if<PrivateBool && (__VA_ARGS__), int>::type = 0
```

And use if even for non-templated function calls:

```
template<REQUIRES(sizeof(int)==4)>
int fun() {return 0;}

int main()
{ 
    fun(); //only if sizeof(int)==4
}
```

The original `REQUIRES` I use is from this [post](http://pfultz2.com/blog/2014/11/08/non-template-constraints/).

What are the other good techniques?

---

Some examples of SFINAE that require some, or long time to understand for reader that just started the adventure with SFINAE:

**Pre-C++11 SFINAE example ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)):**

```
template <typename T>
struct has_typedef_foobar {
    // Types "yes" and "no" are guaranteed to have different sizes,
    // specifically sizeof(yes) == 1 and sizeof(no) == 2.
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <typename C>
    static yes& test(typename C::foobar*);

    template <typename>
    static no& test(...);

    // If the "sizeof" of the result of calling test<T>(nullptr) is equal to sizeof(yes),
    // the first overload worked and T has a nested type named foobar.
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Comment: This looks so cool!

Comment: Honestly, why not just `typename std::enable_if< sizeof(int)==4, int > =0`?  Ah, it does not depend on a template parameter.  Why the `requires_enum`?  Signature collision?

Comment: @See the link to the post I added below the example.

Comment: So, `REQUIRES` clause on `fun` as written on a system with 8-byte `int` generates an ill-formed program, no diagnostic required, on systems where the REQUIREment would be statically false, if the body depends on the 4-byte-ness of the `int` to be well-formed.  This is because there is no set of template argument values you can pass that would make the body of the function be valid.  It is unclear in the standard if a similar problem occurs if you try to use it to disable a template member of a template class depending on the template class parameters.

Comment: @xinaiz: Have you ever hit the wall with the REQUIRES() solution?

Comment: For the generic question in the title, see [c++ - Templated check for the existence of a class member function? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function?noredirect=1&lq=1). (despite the specific title, there are many generic answers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working with C++11 (the example code contains `std::enable_if`, so I guess this is the case) or a successive revision, I would use a `static_assert` in this case:

```
int fun() {
    static_assert(sizeof(int)==4, "!");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    fun();
}
```

You don't have a set of *functions* from which to pick a working one up.
As I've been said once, this is more a *substitution failure is always an error* than a *substitution failure is not an error*.
What you want is a compile-time trigger and a `static_assert` does it with gentle error messages.

Of course, it's also far easier to read than a complicated sfinae expression too!!

---

If you want to choose between two functions and you don't want to use template machinery or macros, do not forget that overloading is part of the language (pre-C++11 working example):

```
#include <iostream>

template<bool> struct tag {};
int fun(tag<true>) { return 0; } 
int fun(tag<false>) { return 1; }
int fun() { return fun(tag<sizeof(int) == 4>()); }

int main() {
    std::cout << fun() << std::endl;
}
```

This can be easily extended to the cases where the functions are more than two:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int> struct tag {};
int fun(tag<0>) { return 0; }
int fun(tag<1>) { return 1; }
int fun(tag<2>) { return 2; }

int fun(bool b) {
    if(b) { return fun(tag<0>()); }
    else { return fun(tag<(sizeof(int) == 4) ? 1 : 2>());
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fun(false) << std::endl;
}
```

You can put those functions in an anonymous namespace and get away with them.

---

Of course, note also that in pre-C++11 we were authorized to write `enable_if` and all the other things from `type_traits` for ourselves.
As an example:

```
template<bool b, typename = void>
struct enable_if { };

template<typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

Comment: That's true that it was overkill for the given example, but that was also just for the sake of example :)

Comment: @BlackMoses Well, if you have more than one function from which to choose, I would use `enable_if` as a return type. It's easy to define in pre-C++11.

Comment: @BlackMoses Added more details to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Enable if is pretty easy to implement. Take a look at this implementation:

```
template<bool b, typename T = void>
struct enable_if {
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct enable_if<false, T> {};
```

In C++11 I usually declare some aliases. Since you're stuck in pre C++11 era, you can do that instead:

```
template<bool b>
struct enable_if_parameter : enable_if<b, int*> {};
```

Then you can use the struct like this:

```
template<typename T, typename enable_if_parameter<(sizeof(T) >= 0)>::type = 0>
void someFunc() {
    // ...
}
```

---

If you can allow yourself some C++17, you could do that:

```
template<bool b>
using enable_if_parameter = std::enable_if_t<b, int*>;
```

And then do that:

```
template<typename T, enable_if_parameter<std::is_same_v<T, int>> = 0>
```

---

I also love the `void_t` idom to create new type traits:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_callme : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_callme<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().callme())>> : std::true_type {};
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++03 you simply write `enable_if` yourself.  It requires no C++11 features.

The reason why you use different techniques is that the pre-C++11 compilers sometimes have a funny definition of what SFINAE and what should be an error.  MSVC is the current major compiler who still (in the pre-C++17 era) has very quirky definition of what is valid SFINAE due to their "SFINAE decltype" issues.

---

In C++11 you should write `void_t` and `enable_if_t` to simplify your SFINAE stuff.

You should also write this:

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class always_void, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;
```

which lets you write traits and ask if something is valid easily (can you call a method?  Create an alias that does a `decltype` on the invocation, then ask if you can apply the type to the alias).  This is still needed in C++14 and 17, but C++20 probably will get `is_detected` which serves a similar purpose.

So `can_print` is:

```
template<class T>using print_result = decltype(
  std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()
);
template<class T>using can_print = can_apply< print_result, T >;
```

it is either truthy or falsy depending on if `<<` works on a stream with it.

In C++14 you can start using hana-style metaprogramming to create lambdas that do type manipulation for you.  In C++17 they become `constexpr`, which gets rid of some issues.

---

Using techniques like the OP's macro tends to lead to ill formed programs, no diagnostic required.  This is because if a template has no valid template parameters that would lead to the body of the template being valid code, your program is ill formed, no diagnostic required.

So this:

```
template<REQUIRES(sizeof(int)==4)>
int fun() {
  // code that is ill-formed if `int` does not have size 4
}
```

will most likely compile and run and "do what you want", but it is actually an ill-formed program when `sizeof(int)` is `8`.

The same may be true of using this technique to disable methods on classes based on the template arguments of the class.  The stanard is unclear on the issue, so I avoid it.

The `REQUIRES` macro tries to hide how it works behind magic, but it is far too easy to step over the line and generate an ill-formed program.  Hiding the magic when the details of the magic cause your code to be ill-formed is not a good plan.

---

Tag dispatching can be used to simplify otherwise complex SFINAE issues.  It can be used to order overloads or pick between them, or pass more than one bundle of types to a helper template function.

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct overload_priority : overload_priority<N-1> {};
template<>
struct overload_priority<0> {};
```

Now you can pass `overload_priority<50>{}` to a set of functions, and the one with the *highest* `overload_priority<?>` in that slot will be preferred.

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T;};

namespace details {
  inline int fun( tag_t<int[4]> ) { return 0; }
  inline int fun( tag_t<int[8]> ) { return 1; }
}
int fun() { return details::fun( tag_t<int[sizeof(int)]>{} ); }
```

just dispatched to a different function depending on the size of `int`.

Both `fun` overloads get compiled and checked, so you don't run into the stealth ill-formed program problem.

A function whose validity is *not* a function of its template arguments is *not* safe to use in C++.  You must use a different tactic.  Machinery that makes this easier to do just makes it easier to write ill-formed programs.