# Eigen 3.3.4 compilation error on MIPS Compiler (C++98)

Tags: c++, templates, mips, eigen, greenhills

I compile Eigen 3.3.4 under Multi-2000 (Green Hill) MIPS C++ compiler.
After I solved some align macro issue in Macros.h, I met a problem again for some template expression.
Find the Error Details as below. I know it should be some issue for my old C++ compiler, but anyone whom can propose an work around it will be greatly appreciated.

```
"C:\Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h", line 389
: error:
          expression must have pointer-to-class type
    template <typename C> static meta_yes testFunctor(C const *,typename enable_if<(sizeof(return_ptr<C>()->operator()())>0)>::type * =
 0);
                                                                                           ^

"C:\Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h", line 389
: error:
          incomplete type is not allowed
    template <typename C> static meta_yes testFunctor(C const *,typename enable_if<(sizeof(return_ptr<C>()->operator()())>0)>::type * =
 0);
                                                                     ^
```

So The Problem must be inside expression as below. But I really can not figure it out.

```
  template <typename C> static meta_yes testFunctor(C const *,typename enable_if<(sizeof(return_ptr<C>()->operator()())>0)>::type * = 0);
```

> **Update 8/25**-> whether "typename enable_if" cause this?

Comment: Use an older version of Eigen. I had similar issues before upgrading my compiler.

Comment: `std::enable_if` is C++11.

Comment: @Jens Munk, nice to know it. Is it Eigen2 you refer?

Comment: No, I just went back to an earlier version of Eigen 3, Eigen 3.2. I also had problems compiling the latest Eigen using MSVC 2013, but that's another story

Comment: @You `std::enable_if` is C++11 but you can also implement your own `enable_if` in C++98.  However, many old compilers do not support SFINAE properly.

Comment: Thanks@Henri I suddenly found sth useful in the link below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727409/how-to-simplify-complicated-sfinae-syntax-in-pre-c11-c11-14-and-17/39733571#39733571