# Inconsistencies with conditional noexcept and overloads

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, argument-dependent-lookup, noexcept

I have an issue which is quite similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781244/why-does-order-of-declaring-function-changes-overload-chosen-by-sfinae) one.

In short, I have a `magic` method, which is `noexcept` if another method is `noexcept`.

The weird thing is that this "another method" has two overloads, and the compiler chooses the **second** overload to determine `magic` `noexcept`-ness.

However, when `magic` is called later on, the **first** overload is called, but the `noexcept`-ness of `magic` remains the same!

Here is the wandbox [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XwROqTUJqIaCiYU2)

From what I understand:

1. `noexcept(magic(dummy2{}))` calls
2. `noexcept(noexcept(adl_caller(...))` which falls back to
3. `adl_caller(..., priority_tag<0>) noexcept`since `user_method(dummy2)` is not known by the compiler at this point.

Fair enough, however, how is `user_method(dummy2)` called 3 lines above?
Is this intended by the Standard?

Sorry if I'm not clear enough.

```
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned N> struct priority_tag : priority_tag<N - 1> {};
template <> struct priority_tag<0> {};

template <typename T>
auto adl_caller(T t, priority_tag<1>) noexcept(noexcept(user_method(t)))
    -> decltype(user_method(t)) {
  std::cout << "first adl_caller overload" << std::endl;
  user_method(t);
}

// tricky noexcept ...
template <typename T> void adl_caller(T, priority_tag<0>) noexcept {
  std::cout << "second adl_caller overload" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void magic(T t) noexcept(noexcept(adl_caller(t, priority_tag<1>{}))) {
  adl_caller(t, priority_tag<1>{});
}

struct dummy {};
struct dummy2 {};

// un-commenting this line makes the above call to cout print '0'
// void user_method(dummy2);

void user_method(dummy)
{
  // user_method(dummy2) is declared after this point
  // this line prints '1', since magic falls back to the second adl_caller overload
  std::cout << "noexcept?: " << noexcept(magic(dummy2{})) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "dummy method called" << std::endl;
  // however, the first adl_caller overload is called here ...
  magic(dummy2{});
}

void user_method(dummy2)
{
  std::cout << "dummy2 method called" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  magic(dummy{});
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[[temp.point]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.point#8):

> A specialization for a function template [...] may
>   have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, and
>   in addition to the points of instantiation described above, for any
>   such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the
>   translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a
>   point of instantiation. [...] If two different points of instantiation
>   give a template specialization different meanings according to the
>   one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic
>   required.

Compare [[temp.dep.candidate]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.dep.candidate):

> For a function call where the *postfix-expression* is a dependent
>   name, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules
>   ([basic.lookup.unqual], [basic.lookup.argdep]) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup, only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces ([basic.lookup.argdep]), only function declarations found in either
>     the template definition context or the template instantiation context
>     are found.
>
> If the call would be ill-formed or would find a better match had the lookup within the associated namespaces considered all the function
>   declarations with external linkage introduced in those namespaces in
>   all translation units, not just considering those declarations found
>   in the template definition and template instantiation contexts, then
>   the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: I think I understand some parts of those paragraphs, but they're a bit too obscure to me. I only have one TU and no external linkage functions in my example, how is the last paragraph related to the code I linked? If I understand correctly, the `magic` method is linked to the first paragraph, but I have some trouble grasping the exact reason. Thanks a lot for the standard excerpts though